# Troubles with offline messages using mqtt.js and Mosca

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

I'm trying to learn how to send offline messages using [mqtt.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) and [Mosca](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mosca) based on the [author's demo](http://mcollina.github.io/mqtt_and_nodejs/#14) and [other instructions](https://github.com/arvindr21/mqttApp).  Below is what I attempted, but I'm not sure why my listening client works online, but not when the subscription process includes offline configuration (QoS, clientId, clean).

1.Start a standalone Mosca broker using:

```
npm install mosca bunyan -g
mosca -v | bunyan
```

2.Run the following scripts (listed below) sequentially:

```
node subscribe.js   // User8 subscribes to topic called Channel-01 with QoS=1, then closes connection
node send.js        // TxUser sends a message on Channel-01
node listen.js      // User8 reconnects and should see TxUser's message
```

3.Attempt to identify why `listen.js` does not receive TxUser's message.

Here are my scripts:

**subscribe.js**
User8 subscribes to a topic called `Channel-01` with `QoS=1`, then closes connection.

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

var client = mqtt.connect({
    servers: [{ host: 'localhost', port: 1883 }]
    , clientId:"User8"
    , clean:false
});

client.subscribe('Channel-01', {qos:1} , function(){
  console.log("Subscriber Client: subscribed and closing connection.");
  client.end();
});
```

**send.js**
TxUser sends a message on Channel-01

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

var client = mqtt.connect({
  servers: [{ host: 'localhost', port: 1883 }]
  , clientId:"TxUser"
  , clean:false
});

client.on('connect', function(){
  client.publish('Channel-01', '* * * IMPORTANT msg ' + Date() + ' * * *' , function() {
    client.end( function (){
      console.log('Sender Client: published message and closed connection');
    });
  });
});
```

**listen.js**
User8 reconnects and should see TxUser's message

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

var client = mqtt.connect({
  servers: [{ host: 'localhost', port: 1883 }]
  , clientId:"User8"
  , clean:false
});

client.subscribe('Channel-01');

client.on('message', function(topic, message) {
  // this is never fired when offline options (QoS, clientId, clean) 
  // are configured in subscribe.js 
  console.log('Listener Client: Message Received = ',message.toString());
});

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Listener Client: Exiting');
  client.end();
},10*1000);
```

**package.js**

```
{
  "name": "MQTT-Test-System",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "mosca": "1.0.1",
    "mqtt": "1.6.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured this out.  Apparently, I just needed to add `{qos:1}` in the publish statement within the `send.js` script.  So it should look like:

```
client.publish('Channel-01', '* * * IMPORTANT msg ' + Date() + ' * * *' , {qos:1}, function() {...etc
```

To clarify the MQTT.js introduction/demo slides, I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/mcollina/mqtt_and_nodejs/pull/1) to the author and the updated slides are [here](http://mcollina.github.io/mqtt_and_nodejs/).